# Can't play mp3 with MediaElement on WP7 emulator

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have an app where I have some prerecorded text to speech (As there is no default support for text to speech) then I want to play them like this

```
var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
mediaElement.Source = new Uri("sound.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0);
mediaElement.Play();
```

But nothing happens, do I HAVE to create a "real" control in my UI? I just want to play this sound when an event happens, I get no errors or nothing, nomatter if the mp3 is in the default folder or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not playing is because you haven't added it to the Visual Tree. When you create a `MediaElement` programmatically, it needs to be added somewhere in the tree. You'll have to create a 'real control' in your UI, but it doesn't have to be seen.

```
var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
mediaElement.Source = new Uri("sound.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(mediaElement); //Add to visual tree
mediaElement.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what happens in your code *after* `mediaElement` is declared. Currently, as soon as the method you declare it in ends, `mediaElement` will fall out of scope and become eligible for garbage collection.

You need to either:

- Parent `mediaElement` to something, perhaps your UI
- Make `mediaElement` a static field on the class

All that said, is playing through `MediaElement` supported in the Emulator?

Comment: The Mediaelement variable is accually a global variable so it should stay in scope, just typed the var infront to make it easier to read.